# parsing recursive array of JSONs in angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular

so I have an angular component that has a array of nested jsons... I want to use a service to load these nested jsons into their own objects in an array so I can look up via the ID.

there may be a better way to just be able to lookup through a large json based on the id, but I'm really unsure how to do this angular

thanks for checking out my Q

```js
//angular component

public nodeList = [
    {name: 'production 1', id: '1' , children: [
      {name: 'test one', id: '2' ,  children: [
        {name: 'development one', id: '3' ,  children: []}
      ]},
      {name: 'test two', id: '4' ,  children: [
        {name: 'development two', id: '5' ,  children: []}
      ]}
    ]}
  ];
  public nodeList2 = [
    {name: 'production 2', id: '6' ,  children: [
      {name: 'test one', id: '7' ,  children: [
        {name: 'development three', id: '8' ,  children: []}
      ]},
      {name: 'test two', id: '9' ,  children: [
        {name: 'development four', id: '10' ,  children: []}
      ]}
    ]}
  ];
  
  constructor (private sidenav: SideNavService) {
    this.sidenav.loadNodes(this.nodeList);
    this.sidenav.loadNodes(this.nodeList2);
  }
 
 
 
 //angular service
 
  allNodes: Array<any> //maybe this should not be of type any?
  
  //here I want to pass in lists like the one shown in the above component and parse through it a put each of the jsons into the list allNodes
  loadNodes(tree) {
   
  }
  
  //here I want to pass in an ID and return that json, no matter how far it is nested, at this point just to get the name (the name may not be unique)
  lookupNode(id: String) {
  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive method along these lines to flatten your array (changed syntax to run here inline):

```js
const nodeList = [
    {name: 'production 1', id: '1' , children: [
      {name: 'test one', id: '2' ,  children: [
        {name: 'development one', id: '3' ,  children: []}
      ]},
      {name: 'test two', id: '4' ,  children: [
        {name: 'development two', id: '5' ,  children: []}
      ]}
    ]}
  ];
  const nodeList2 = [
    {name: 'production 2', id: '6' ,  children: [
      {name: 'test one', id: '7' ,  children: [
        {name: 'development three', id: '8' ,  children: []}
      ]},
      {name: 'test two', id: '9' ,  children: [
        {name: 'development four', id: '10' ,  children: []}
      ]}
    ]}
  ];
  
  function flattenArr(arr){
    return arr.reduce((output, obj) => {
      let children = obj.children
      output.push({
        name: obj.name,
        id: obj.id
      })
      if(children && children.length){
        output = output.concat(flattenArr(children))
      }
      return output
    }, [])
  }
  
  console.log(flattenArr(nodeList))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of flattening it, you could traverse through the array with the help of simple recursion.

```
  lookupNode(arr: Array<Object>, id: string) {
    if (arr.id === id) {
      return arr;
    } else if (arr.children) {
      for(let i = 0; i < arr.children.length; i++) {
        let temp = this.lookupNode(arr.children[i], id);
        if (temp !== null) {
          return temp;
        }
      }
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```